# Read and display CSV in text widget using loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x, csv, tkinter

I have a program that is reading in a csv file and outputting a number of fields into a text widget, my initial hack of allocating variables works fine, but doesnt give me any flexibility to display more than three lines from the csv file, so i need to go down the route of using a loop routine. Unfortunately I'm unsure how to attack this with what I currently have. My hack code follows below.

```
def checkcsv():
        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    descDwg1=(row['Drawings1'])
                    descIss1=(row['Issue1'])
                    descDwg2=(row['Drawings2'])
                    descIss2=(row['Issue2'])
                    descDwg3=(row['Drawings3'])
                    descIss3=(row['Issue3'])
                    self.outputQty.insert(1.0, descQty)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(1.0, descPN, "", ": ", "", descInfo)
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg3, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss3, "", "\n")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg2, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss2, "", "\n")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg1, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss1, "", "\n")
                    self.outputQty.configure(state="disabled")          
                    self.outputDesc.configure(state="disabled")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

[image]

Comment: That's probably not enough code and description of your problem. I am using the `pandas` module for handling csv files. Have a look at it. Might be easier for this purpose because it allows you nice workflow with the file. It is hard to imagine what `but doesnt give me any flexibility to display more than three lines from the csv file` without any code. What is your question?

Comment: the three lines comment revolves around the number of variables I'm using to display the drawing information. ie DRAWINGS1 and ISSUE1 displays one lines, DRAWINGS2, ISSUE2 the second line etc. So with the way the code is currently written if I wanted 10 lines I'd need to add a whole lot more variables which isnt ideal and hence why I'd like to work out how to do this using a loop

Comment: Ok, could you please post the csv and preferably more code? Also clearer explanation of what you need to do with that data.. I am still confused, you should probablx use more lists or even write nee simple object to store your data..

Comment: Added a screen shot that may help,ignore the reference to the outputQty and outputDesc as these are other text widget references,In my csv code DescDwg relates to the numbers eg 1931-125 and DescIss relates to the letter that follows Issue. My current code has 3 different DescDwg variables and 3 DescIss variables which allows me to display 3 lines in my text widget, to add additional lines I need additional variables (with how my code is written), what I would like to do is have a single Dwg and Iss variable that can be reused in a loop, allowing for as many lines of info as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, to be honest I feel like one of us is missing something quite easy and obvious. I've tweaked your code a little bit. But all I've done is adding one `for` loop, you'll. Maybe this is what you are looking for.. If not, hopefully we'll be able to specify the problem better:

```
def checkcsv():
        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    # I've added the following four lines of code
                    # and commented out some lines, hopefully it is clear
                    # how to add more descDwg, descIss, simply change the range
                    # assuming your csv work that way = DrawingsX, IssueX...
                    for i in xrange(1,4):
                        descDwg=(row['Drawings'+ str(i)])
                        descIss=(row['Issue'+ str(i)])
                        # check, whether the issue is empty if so, skip to the next one
                        if descIss ==  '':
                            continue
                        self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss, "", "\n")

                    # descDwg1=(row['Drawings1'])
                    # descIss1=(row['Issue1'])
                    # descDwg2=(row['Drawings2'])
                    # descIss2=(row['Issue2'])
                    # descDwg3=(row['Drawings3'])
                    # descIss3=(row['Issue3'])

                    self.outputQty.insert(1.0, descQty)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(1.0, descPN, "", ": ", "", descInfo)
                    # self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg3, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss3, "", "\n")
                    # self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg2, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss2, "", "\n")
                    # self.dwgoutputbox.insert(1.0, descDwg1, "dwg", "  Issue: ", "", descIss1, "", "\n")
                    self.outputQty.configure(state="disabled")          
                    self.outputDesc.configure(state="disabled")
                    self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: thank you works well, I just had to substitute range for xrange as it appears python 3 no longer supports it. Just one extra question, if say I have a range of 7 (i.e. 6 drawing and 6 issue columns in my csv file) but for a particular item I'm searching the csv for only 3 of those columns have data how do I prevent an error or the lines from displaying ? What I'm getting with this is 3 extra lines with the word "ISSUE" followed by a carriage return - which is technically correct as there is no data to display but undesirable.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the delay. Python 2 `range` was removed and `xrange` is now (in Python 3) called `range`, my mistake. I've added an `if` statement to check, whether the issue is empty or not. If it is empty, the for loop `continue`s and the textbox is not populated with empty issue.

Comment: Great, I'd advise you to maybe expand your Python skills a little bit before tackling bigger projects in tkinter. Good luck!